# Count up timer doesn't work (setInterval part)

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, stopwatch

I noticed that the setInterval part makes the code not work. No error is being shown. It works when I manually press the button one at a time.

```js
const stopWatch = document.getElementById("time");
let totalSecs = 0;
const start = document.getElementById("start");


let timeCount = setInterval(seconds, 1000);
let seconds = () => {
  start.innerHTML = "Clicked!";
  ++totalSecs;
  let hr = Math.floor(totalSecs / 3600);
  let min = Math.floor(totalSecs / 60);
  let sec = totalSecs - hr * 3600 - min * 60;
  stopWatch.innerHTML = `${hr} : ${min} : ${sec}`;
}

document.addEventListener("click", seconds);
```

```html
<div id="time">
</div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: isn't it totalSecs++ ?

Comment: @Strella There's no difference in this case. It only makes a difference if you use the result of the increment.

Comment: Didn't you see the error in the console? You need to put `setInterval()` after the function definition. You're trying to refer to the variable before it's defined.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I moved the setInterval() below the function definition and it worked!

Comment: Functions declared with `let` or `const` aren't hoisted like functions defined with `function`.

Comment: Isn't it the same? I just used an arrow function declaration which is shorter.

Comment: Your arrow function is held in a variable, variables cannot be accessed before they are declared. Unless there is good reason not do so, normal function declarations are always the way to go.

Comment: @DavePritlove, I see. Can you cite circumstances where using an arrow function is preferred over using regular function declaration?